# How to enable the quick fix for auto import using vscode for python and PySide6

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I use vscode as my python IDE, and had installed some nessary plugins such as python and pylance for it. But now I have a problem, the pylance for vscode could not reconizge the PySide6 modules for quick fix auto import, like following picture shows:
[image]
But the quick fix work for other modules.
[image]

Could someone help to point out how to resolve it? It worked before but one day could not work any more.

Comment: with extension [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions) you can add a few quick fix actions to detected problems that insert some `import` statement at the top

Comment: Thanks, it should be an alternative way, but I think there would be an automatic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but normally, we will not act like this. We will not type a complex or long className then import it through a quick fix. at most we type `sys` and import it immediately.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes I don't know which module the pyside6 class I used is in, so I need the quick fix  to give some suggestions, and it actually worked before, but one day it didn't work anymore. I reinstalled the vscode and plugins, but was not helping.

Comment: @Alpha Liu Yes it is, so I submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18842) on GitHub, it's a little different from your request.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in Pylance version 2022.4.0, please see the https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2533